# Mqtt send message to anyone who connected to the server

Tags: java, mqtt

I want to use **mqtt** to send message to everyone who connected Mqtt server.how can i do?(i use java  client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQTT is a topic based, so in order to send a message to all clients they would need to be subscribed to a specific topic.

Comment: if one is not online ,when he login in ,does he receive the message?